# How to close div on tab 1 if i move to tab 2 ( For Mobile )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a query.
I am willing to close div on page 1 if user clicks at any link on the page or inside the div and moves to another tab or link that opens after clicking anywhere inside page 1 . On Mobile , this code is working if a link from page 1 is opened in same tab.. if I click a link on tab 1 and it opens a page in tab 2 , the div does not close ...

this does not seem to work on mobile . How to achieve similar working on mobile ?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
document.getElementById('ControlCode').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('ControlCode').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Comment: for mobile i have tried onpagehide blur focus everything but nothing works for me :(

Comment: i figured it out 
window.onblur works on mobile browsers